# Changing latex table text direction?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, row-height, text-direction

I want to change the table generated by the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292525/making-latex-multicolumn-width-wider-in-rmarkdown) so that the first column looks like the figure below by **1-** changing the text direction in the first column. I made some changes regarding this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table) but still have a problem.

**Desired output:**
[image]

**Current output**:
[image]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption[Transformation table]{Transformations generated by Mach et al. Y in a dark cell: highly recommended, Y in a light cell: usable, N in a dark cell: unusable \label{tab:power}}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={XXXXXX},
  vlines,
  hlines,
  cells={halign=c},
  column{1-2}={halign=l},
  hspan=even,
}
& \SetCell[c=5]{halign=c,bg=gray,fg=white} Type of Distribution & & & &\\ 
\SetCell[r=5]{bg=gray,fg=white} \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Type of \\  Transformation}}} & & Lognormal & Exponential & Gamma & Weibull \\
& Box-Cox & Y & Y & \SetCell{bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries} Y & \SetCell{bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries} Y \\ 
& Exponential & Y & Y & Y & Y\\
& Simple power & Y & \SetCell{bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries} Y & \SetCell{bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries} Y & \SetCell{bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries} Y \\
& Logarithmic & \SetCell{bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries} Y & Y & \SetCell{font=\bfseries} N & \SetCell{font=\bfseries} N \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{text}\\
 \hline
 \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{rota}}} & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\rotatebox` before the `\parbox` (and don't use `\multirow`  in a `tblr`, that's no longer defined there):

```
---
title: "misc"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    extra_dependencies: caption
    number_sections: yes
fig_caption: yes
classoption: table
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tabularray}
language:
  label:
    fig: !expr function(x) sprintf("**Figure %s.** ", x)
fontsize: 11pt
urlcolor: blue
---


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption[Transformation table]{Transformations generated by Mach et al. Y in a dark cell: highly recommended, Y in a light cell: usable, N in a dark cell: unusable \label{tab:power}}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={lXXXXX},
  vlines,
  hlines,
  cells={halign=c},
  column{1-2}={halign=l},
  vspan=even,
  cell{1}{2}={halign=c,bg=gray,fg=white},
  cell{2}{1}={bg=gray,fg=white},
  cell{3}{5-6}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},  
  cell{5}{4-6}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},    
  cell{6}{3}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},      
}
& \SetCell[c=5]{} Type of Distribution & & & &\\ 
\SetCell[r=5]{} \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\centering Type of Transformation}} & & Lognormal & Exponential & Gamma & Weibull \\
& Box-Cox & Y & Y & Y & Y \\ 
& Exponential & Y & Y & Y & Y\\
& Simple power & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
& Logarithmic & Y & Y & N & N \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: What about table height?

Comment: @Abbas You shouldn't ask multiple questions in one post. Ask exactly one question per question and move all additional ones to a new post.

Comment: I will ask again about table height