# Changing dimensions (height and width ) of latex table generated tabularray

Tags: latex, r-markdown, row-height

I need to make the LaTeX table generated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293556/changing-latex-table-text-direction-and-total-table-height/73293695?noredirect=1#73293695) smaller in height either by changing the total height or each row height, whichever looks better. How can I do that?
Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption[Transformation table]{Transformations generated by Mach et al. Y in a dark cell: highly recommended, Y in a light cell: usable, N in a dark cell: unusable \label{tab:power}}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={lXXXXX},
  vlines,
  hlines,
  cells={halign=c},
  column{1-2}={halign=l},
  vspan=even,
  cell{1}{2}={halign=c,bg=gray,fg=white},
  cell{2}{1}={bg=gray,fg=white},
  cell{3}{5-6}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},  
  cell{5}{4-6}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},    
  cell{6}{3}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},      
}
& \SetCell[c=5]{} Type of Distribution & & & &\\ 
\SetCell[r=5]{} \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\centering Type of Transformation}} & & Lognormal & Exponential & Gamma & Weibull \\
& Box-Cox & Y & Y & Y & Y \\ 
& Exponential & Y & Y & Y & Y\\
& Simple power & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
& Logarithmic & Y & Y & N & N \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra height comes from the `\parbox`. If you reduce the width of the `\parbox` a bit, the rows become less tall.

If you need the rows to be even narrower, you can change the `rowsep` (but you'll have to ditch the idea of rotated text then).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption[Transformation table]{Transformations generated by Mach et al. Y in a dark cell: highly recommended, Y in a light cell: usable, N in a dark cell: unusable \label{tab:power}}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={lXXXXX},
  vlines,
  hlines,
  cells={halign=c},
  column{1-2}={halign=l},
  vspan=even,
  cell{1}{2}={halign=c,bg=gray,fg=white},
  cell{2}{1}={bg=gray,fg=white},
  cell{3}{5-6}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},  
  cell{5}{4-6}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},    
  cell{6}{3}={bg=lightgray,font=\bfseries},      
%  rowsep = 0mm
}
& \SetCell[c=5]{} Type of Distribution & & & &\\ 
\SetCell[r=5]{} \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering Type of Transformation}} & & Lognormal & Exponential & Gamma & Weibull \\
& Box-Cox & Y & Y & Y & Y \\ 
& Exponential & Y & Y & Y & Y\\
& Simple power & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
& Logarithmic & Y & Y & N & N \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]